# Simulation of Quantum pseudo-telepathy

Tags: matrix, physics, tensors, quantum-computing

I would like to mathematically simulate [Quantum pseudo-telepathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_pseudo-telepathy) on [The magic square game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_pseudo-telepathy#The_magic_square_game) from Wikipedia.

In section [Pseudo-telepathic strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_pseudo-telepathy#Pseudo-telepathic_strategies) we can read:

> The trick is for Alice and Bob to share an entangled quantum state and
> to use specific measurements on their components of the entangled
> state to derive the table entries. A suitable correlated state
> consists of a pair of entangled Bell states:
>
> ${\displaystyle \left|\varphi \right\rangle ={\frac
>  {1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\bigg(}\left|+\right\rangle_{a}\otimes
>  \left|+\right\rangle _{b}+\left|-\right\rangle _{a}\otimes
>  \left|-\right\rangle _{b}{\bigg )}\otimes {\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\bigg
>  (}\left|+\right\rangle_{c}\otimes \left|+\right\rangle
>  _{d}+\left|-\right\rangle _{c}\otimes\left|-\right\rangle _{d}{\bigg )}}$
>
> here ${\displaystyle \left|+\right\rangle }$ and ${\displaystyle\left|-\right\rangle }$
> are eigenstates of the Pauli operator $S_x$ with
> eigenvalues $+1$ and $−1$, respectively, whilst the subscripts $a$,
> $b$, $c$, and $d$ identify the components of each Bell state, with $a$
> and $c$ going to Alice, and $b$ and $d$ going to Bob. The symbol
> ${\displaystyle \otimes }$  represents a tensor product.

And so on...

My code resembles the math of that section:

```
Ket[\[CurlyPhi]] == 
  TensorProduct[
   1/Sqrt[2] (TensorProduct[Subscript[Ket["+"], a], Subscript[
       Ket["+"], b]] + 
      TensorProduct[Subscript[Ket["-"], a], Subscript[Ket["-"], b]]), 
   1/Sqrt[2] (TensorProduct[Subscript[Ket["+"], c], Subscript[
       Ket["+"], d]] + 
      TensorProduct[Subscript[Ket["-"], c], Subscript[Ket["-"], 
       d]])] // HoldForm

Format[i] := "I"
Format[S[n_]] := Subscript[S, n]
msquarev = {{TensorProduct[i, S[z]], TensorProduct[S[z], i], 
    TensorProduct[S[z], S[z]]}, {TensorProduct[S[x], i], 
    TensorProduct[i, S[x]], 
    TensorProduct[S[x], 
     S[x]]}, {-TensorProduct[S[x], S[z]], -TensorProduct[S[z], S[x]], 
    TensorProduct[S[y], S[y]]}};
msquare = msquarev /. TensorProduct -> KroneckerProduct;
Grid[msquarev, Frame -> All]

i = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
S[x] = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
S[y] = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}};
S[z] = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};

Dot @@ msquare[[1]] == Dot @@ msquare[[2]] == Dot @@ msquare[[3]] == 
 IdentityMatrix[4]

Dot @@ msquare[[All, 1]] == Dot @@ msquare[[All, 2]] == 
 Dot @@ msquare[[All, 3]] == -IdentityMatrix[4]

Clear[i, S, msquarev, msquare]
```

[image]

The two `True`s confirm that the code should be OK since product of each row should be identity matrix and product of each column should be "negative" identity matrix.

Now I would like to do the math of measurements done by Alice and Bob for each possible case.

Suppose the first row and the first column are selected. Alice measures particle $a$ spin along z-axis as $+1$ and particle $c$ spin along z-axis as $+1$. Bob measures particle $b$ spin along x-axis as $+1$ and particle $d$ along z-axis as $+1$.

How the math would look like for this first possible case and for other `36` (if I am not mistaken) cases?

`36=9*4`

`9` items in the magic square and `4` possible spin measurements for Alice/Bob.